# How can i send mail using + (id)queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:(GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersOrNil; in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-api-client, gmail-api, google-schemas

We are trying to develop a mail iOS application, I have integrated google gmail-api, also pulled message from my inbox.

I get struck send mail through

```
+ (id)queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:(GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersOrNil;
```

How can we use GTLUploadParameters to send mail ?

Comment: check this link https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Gmail/Generated/GTLQueryGmail.m?r=405

Comment: Check this https://github.com/search?q=queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:++extension%3Am&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)sendEmail:(WLGmailMessage *)message completionBlock:(void (^)(NSError *))completionBlock
{
    GTLGmailMessage *gtlGmailMessage = [[GTLGmailMessage alloc] init];
    gtlGmailMessage.raw = message.rawString;

    // upload parameter
//        GTLUploadParameters *upParam = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:GTLDecodeWebSafeBase64(messageRawStr) MIMEType:@"message/rfc822"];

    // query
    GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:nil];
    query.message = gtlGmailMessage;
    [_service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"SENT EMAIL");
        }
        completionBlock(error);
    }];

}

- (NSString *)rawString
{
    NSMutableString *message = [NSMutableString new];
    [message appendFormat:@"From: %@\n", [_fromAddress rawString]];
    [message appendFormat:@"To: %@\n", [_toAddress rawString]];
    [message appendFormat:@"Subject: %@\n", _subject];
    [message appendFormat:@"Date: %@\n", [self _formattedDate]];
#warning input real ID
    [message appendString:@"Message-ID: <tmpID>\n"];
    [message appendString:@"\n"];
    [message appendString:_body];
    return GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64([message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}

- (NSString *)rawString
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <%@>", _name, _emailAddress];
}
```

Complete Project [here](https://github.com/wyattlam1/WLGmail/tree/75ec653cf08b2228e896a433b0fb704dc603e7eb)

Comment: in swift check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259916/how-send-email-using-gmail-api-in-swift/33264604#33264604